# Why my java process on Linux OS did not show -classpath in java command when I input "ps -ef | grep java"?

Tags: java, linux, shell, hadoop, process

I have this issue about java command when I input the following shell command "ps -ef | grep java".
And I got following commands which shows two java processes

the first process is like "java -Dxxx org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode" which does not specify the -classpath option. this command is confusing me a lot I don't know how it can find the class of "org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode" and other classes or jars that it depends on

the second process is like "java -Dxxx -classpath xxx.jar org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager" which make senses to me what a noraml java command should be like.

Can anyone help me to explain why the first command does not have the classpath?

```
//first process

root      4116     1  0 Jan30 ?        00:07:55 /root/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java -Dproc_namenode -Xmx1000m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5 -Dhadoop.id.str=root -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console -Djava.library.path=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop-root-namenode-hdfs01.log -Dhadoop.home.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5 -Dhadoop.id.str=root -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native -Dhadoop.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS -Dhdfs.audit.logger=INFO,NullAppender -Dhadoop.security.logger=INFO,RFAS org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode

//second process

root      4595     1  0 Jan30 pts/0    00:28:38 /root/jdk1.8.0_181/bin/java -Dproc_resourcemanager -Xmx1000m -Dhadoop.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=yarn-root-resourcemanager-hdfs01.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn-root-resourcemanager-hdfs01.log -Dyarn.home.dir= -Dyarn.id.str=root -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native -Dyarn.policy.file=hadoop-policy.xml -Dhadoop.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dyarn.log.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=yarn-root-resourcemanager-hdfs01.log -Dyarn.log.file=yarn-root-resourcemanager-hdfs01.log -Dyarn.home.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5 -Dhadoop.home.dir=/root/hadoop-2.8.5 -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Dyarn.root.logger=INFO,RFA -Djava.library.path=/root/hadoop-2.8.5/lib/native -classpath /root/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/common/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/hdfs/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/contrib/capacity-scheduler/*.jar:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*:/root/hadoop-2.8.5/etc/hadoop/rm-config/log4j.properties org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.ResourceManager
```

Comment: Because the actual `java` command executed didn't have the argument.  You need to figure out how those commands are actually being started.  My guess is that there are some Hadoop config files or Hadoop commands that need to specify the missing `-classpath`.  (That might be enough to give you a clue about where to start.)

Comment: Check the CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: I think I have got the answer, java process is launched by specifying your classpath manually. However, if you do not specify it, it will seek the path in you environment variable $CLASSPATH, I guess the shell process that launch the java process have already modify the variable $CLASSPATH before launch this java process

Comment: But here's the thing: you can't mix `$CLASSPATH` and `-classpath` arguments.  The latter replace the former.  It is worth reading the documentation carefully about this.

Answer (score 0):

The scripts run `export CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)` or look under `$HADOOP_HOME` for jars.

`-classpath` isn't required Java parameter

You can also use `jps` to see running Java processes, which is what the Hadoop documentation suggests